# Pandas: Reading an CSV file with the intention of creating a 3D array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

First time posting here.
So my question is regarding how to read an CSV file in Pandas with the intention of creating a 2d array with a matrix within each element.

So for instance take this example CSV file

```
1,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3
1,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3
1,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3
```

Where each new line represents a separate matrix
and each semicolon represents a separate row within each matrix
and each comma represents a separate element within each row

So from this I would like to get to this type of array:

```
[
   [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]],
   [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]],
   [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
]
```

Currently, when I use pandas.read_csv() on something like this it'll not read the semicolon as a separator and so something like 1;2 would be read as a string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `sep=';'` and `header=None` (if no header in `csv`). Then you need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html), because `string` functions work only with `Series` (columns of `df`):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""1,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3
1,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3
1,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", header=None)
print (df)
       0      1      2
0  1,1,1  2,2,2  3,3,3
1  1,1,1  2,2,2  3,3,3
2  1,1,1  2,2,2  3,3,3

print (df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',')))
           0          1          2
0  [1, 1, 1]  [2, 2, 2]  [3, 3, 3]
1  [1, 1, 1]  [2, 2, 2]  [3, 3, 3]
2  [1, 1, 1]  [2, 2, 2]  [3, 3, 3]

print (df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(',')).values.tolist())
[[['1', '1', '1'], ['2', '2', '2'], ['3', '3', '3']], 
 [['1', '1', '1'], ['2', '2', '2'], ['3', '3', '3']], 
 [['1', '1', '1'], ['2', '2', '2'], ['3', '3', '3']]]
```

But if need list of `int`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""1,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3
1,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3
1,1,1;2,2,2;3,3,3"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";", header=None)
print (df)
       0      1      2
0  1,1,1  2,2,2  3,3,3
1  1,1,1  2,2,2  3,3,3
2  1,1,1  2,2,2  3,3,3

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].str.split(',')
    #if need convert string numbers to int
    df[col] = [[int(y) for y in x] for x in df[col]]    

print (df.values.tolist())
[[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], 
 [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]], 
 [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]]
```